# Does react-redux's connect pass container's ownProps to presentational component directly?

Tags: react-redux

I found that react-redux's connect will pass container's  ownProps to presentational component directly, but the official document doesn't remind that. Any one else found that?

```
const TodoApp = () => (
    <div>
        <AddTodo name="swf" onClick={age => console.log(age)} />
        <VisibleTodoList />
        <Footer />
    </div>
);
```

Here AddTodo is a container as follows:

```
let AddTodo = ({dispatch, name, onClick}) => {
    let input;
    console.log('name:', name);
    return (
        <div>
            <input ref={node => input = node}></input>
            <button onClick={e => {
                onClick('1000');
                dispatch(addTodo(input.value));
                input.value = '';
            }}>
               Add Todo
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};

AddTodo = connect()(AddTodo);
```

The console.log will indeed print out right word 'swf', and the onClick callback will also print right number 1000. However, I didn't pass that two props manually...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `ownProps` is passed as an optional second argument in `connect`. It often looks something like:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {

   return {
      reduxProp: state.reducer,
      ownProp: ownProps.prop
   };
}
```

But it is indeed in the documentation, [at least on GitHub](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options):

> If your mapStateToProps function is declared as taking two parameters, it will be called with the store state as the first parameter and the props passed to the connected component as the second parameter, and will also be re-invoked whenever the connected component receives new props as determined by shallow equality comparisons. (The second parameter is normally referred to as ownProps by convention.)

To answer your questions, it also states in the docs that if no parameters are passed to `mapStateToProps`, both `ownProps` and `state` will be passed.

> Functions with no mandatory parameters or two parameters will receive ownProps.

In your case, you aren't even specifying a specific `mapStateToProps` function, just a call a call to `connect`. So I believe `react-redux` is treating this as a call to `mapStateToProps` with empty arguments, hence why `ownProps` gets passed.

Comment: Thanks, I knew this, but this is not what I asked. What I asked is even I don't compute state this way (by store's state and the container's ownProps), ownProps will also be passed to my presentational component. I wonder how this happened...

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I have just seen `defaultMergeProps` in react-redux source code, it will merge own props by default.